# MongoDB query on two collections to add/subtract a field in first collection with matched field from second collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've been stuck on this for a couple days and can't seem to figure it out.

Here's a couple example collections in my MongoDB database:
(just an example. sorry if they're not formatted correctly)

**Products :**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e4633eaa7095f26d44a43c3"
    },
    "name": "Acrylic Frame Magnetic",
    "units: "50",
    "fbasku": "AFM-CL-0507-FBA",
    "upc": "642709233954"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e4633eaa7095f26d44a43c4"
    },
    "name": "Apron Polka Dot",
    "units: "488",
    "fbasku": "APD-RD-03PC-FBA",
    "upc": "642709233961"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e4633eaa7095f26d44a43c5"
    },
    "name": "Acrylic Sign Holder - 5x7",
    "units: "632",
    "fbasku": "ASH-GD-0507-FBA",
    "upc": "642709233978"
}
```

**Transactions :**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e44e8ed8f4cd40bd09d5ce8"
    },
    "type": "adjust",
    "fbasku": "AFM-CL-0507-FBA",
    "units": {
        "$numberInt": "25"
    },
    "comment": "example transaction"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e4c9ab642c5a232042f4b67"
    },
    "type": "send",
    "fbasku": "AFM-CL-0507-FBA",
    "units": {
        "$numberInt": "75"
    },
    "comment": ""
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e4c9ab642c5a232042f4b69"
    },
    "type": "send",
    "fbasku": "AFM-CL-0507-FBA",
    "units": {
        "$numberInt": "5"
    },
    "comment": ""
}
```

This is for a REST api I'm trying to build, so when I send a request to get all products, I want to:

1. Get an object containing all the products
2. Look through the transactions collection for each product in the object above, and add/subtract units from the listed unit quantity.
3. Give a response containing an object with the "fbasku", and a new calculated unit quantity for each product.

I got stuck when it came to all the async/await and Promise stuff, don't really understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code - it is a sample of how to do your requirement using native **nodejs-mongodb driver** and **node.js** :

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const dbConnection = async function () {
    /** Connection URL */
    const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'; // Check whether you're passing correct DB name & full formed connection string
    let client;

    try {
        /** Use connect method to connect to the Server */
        client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
        const db = client.db(); // MongoDB would return client and you need to call DB on it.
        let dbResp = await db.collection('Products').aggregate([
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: "Transactions",
                    let: { fbasku: "$fbasku" },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match:
                            {
                                $expr:
                                    { $eq: ["$fbasku", "$$fbasku"] }
                            }
                        },
                        { $project: { units: 1, _id: 0 } }
                    ],
                    as: "transaction_docs"
                }
            }, {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0, fbasku: 1,
                    units: {
                        $add: [{ $toInt: '$units' }, {
                            $reduce: {
                                input: '$transaction_docs',
                                initialValue: 0,
                                in: { $add: ["$$value", "$$this.units"] }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]).toArray();
        client.close();
        return dbResp;
    } catch (err) {
        (client) && client.close();
        console.log(err);
        throw err
    }
};

/** In general dbConnection() has to be in one config file & it needs to be imported where ever db transactions are done like below */

dbConnection().then(res => console.log('Printing at calling ::', res)).catch(err => console.log('Err at Calling ::', err));
```

**Note :** This code has query which assumes **units** in **products** is a string, So we're converting it into int & adding that values to (sum of units of transactions => `intOf(units of a products) + (sum of units of all matched transactions)`).

**Test Query :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e-u3JdXfL8M)